# How to export MapView (Esri, ArcGIS) as an image

Tags: windows-store-apps, gis, arcgis, esri

I've faced the issue - there is no way to export MapView (Esri, ArcGIS) state as an Image on Windows Store App.
There is no embedded functionality and if use RenderTargetBitmap - I've got only black screen.
How can I get Image of MapView?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting the image is effectively treated as a print operation but for the map only (as opposed to using a print template). There are a couple of code samples in the sample repo that go over either server side or [client side](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/sample-code/ClientPrinting/) printing